# Fetching an Array inside JsonArray for JSON PATH

Tags: java, arrays, json, jsonpath, jpath

My JsonBody is

```
{  
   "acr_values":[  
      "AAL1",
      "AAL2"
   ],
   "poc":[  
      {  
         "attribute1":"value1"
      },
      {  
         "attribute1":"value2"
      }
   ]
}
```

I'm trying to fetch the attribute **acr_values** as Array, As I'm expecting Array with in the Json Array as `[ ["AAL1","AAL2"] ]` and wanted to validate it using this snippet.

```
Object valueForAcr_Value = JsonPath.read(AboveJson, $.acr_values);
```

But value is returning as JsonArray **["AAL1", "AAL2"]** where I'm trying to fetch the value as Array. Because when I'm trying to fetch the values for

```
Object valueForAttribute = JsonPath.read(AboveJson, $.poc[*].attribute1);
```

I'm getting the same as Json Array as `["value1" , "value1"]`, how do i differentiate between valueForAcr and ValueForAttribute. Is there any way that i can get the valueForAcr as     `[ ["AA1","AA2"] ]`

Comment: Format your JSON Please, also specify what error you are having.

Comment: why do you need in that format?,